# Error with JavaScript Constructors Under Various Formats

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with code in the following format:

```
Test = {
    baseConstructor: function( a, b ) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;        
    },
    object: new Test.baseConstructor( x, y )
};
```

I get an error saying that this.baseConstructor is not a constructor. So what would I do in this case? I know I could reformat it without using the Test = {} style but is there a way to do it in this format.

Comment: Your code contains syntax errors. Before `object` there should be a `,` and after the baseConstructor call there shouldn't be a `;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `this` at this point as you are not inside an instance. `Test.baseConstructor` also won't work since `Test` has not been assigned yet when the code runs.

Here's a way to do it:

```
var Test = {
    baseConstructor: function( a, b ) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;        
    }
};
Test.object = new Test.baseConstructor(1, 2);
```